# how to store dataset column value in textbox

Tags: c#

i want retrieve the single column value from table and display into textbox. i am using following code but it shows me only single value.

```
com = new SqlCommand("select rid from myclient ", cn);
SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(com);   
DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
da1.Fill(ds1, "myclient");                   
string  str = ds1.Tables["myclient"].Rows[0]["rid"].ToString();
TextBox1.Text = str;
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Do you face any problem? if not you can do it in single statment, TextBox1.Text = ds1.Tables["myclient"].Rows[0]["rid"].ToString();

Comment: You forgot to describe what problem you have with this code and what is expected

Comment: Are you sure there is data in there? Null vallues give an error when casting to string. Try something like ds1.Tables["myclient"].Rows[0]["rid"] == null ? "No data available" : ds1.Tables["myclient"].Rows[0]["rid"].ToString();

Comment: i assume if you need single value from database you can use ExecuteScalar() Function

Comment: Adil  i want full column data . but my code give me single value.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Please follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to rephrase your question. This helps others to understand your Problem and to provide an appropriate answer

Answer (score 1):

It is not clean what you want to do but if you want "all data  into textbox" this is your code.

```
string  str = "";
for(int i =0;i<ds1.Tables["myclient"].Rows.Count();i++)
{
str += ds1.Tables["myclient"].Rows[i]["rid"].ToString();
}
TextBox1.Text = str;
```